# Join on dataframe without a key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am joining two dataframes. Each of the same size, being 287025.

```
dataDF = sample.join(additional_info)
```

The indices are identical, and the dataDF has the correct size, being 287025. However now I seem to have no access to the rows. I try `dataDF[1:9]` and it simply outputs a summary of the df, showing all columns I would expect. I also try `dataDF.head(3)` to show first 3 rows and once again it outputs the summary info for the dataDF.

Am not sure why this join seems to be working, yet alas no rows can be seen - I cannot slice the DF.

Any ideas as to why?

Btw I do not join on the key, as I only want to really join on index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the join is working, but you are seeing a summarized view.

There are a number of display options which can do this, the most likely imo:

```
# if there are more columns than this, you'll see a summarized view
pd.options.display.max_columns = 40 # default is 20
```

*see [working with package options section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#working-with-package-options).*

Comment: pd.set_option('display.width', 400) in ipython/QtConsole

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it seems that your data frame is not displayed because there are too many columns. This is an issue with the output not with the data frame itself.

In addition to Andy's suggestion, you can access a specific set of columns using `df.iloc[]` with two arguments, the first for the rows, the second for the columns.

For  example:

```
print dataDF.iloc[:5,4:10]
```

should print the first 5 rows and the columns 4 through 9.